# Set index.html#divID as my homepage?

Tags: javascript, html

**Hi, my question is, is it possible to set index.html#box02 as my homepage instead of index.html?**

I am building a website with panning divs.

Exactly like http://demos.flesler.com/jquery/scrollTo/

Because of the panning effect, I design the whole site on a single html file - index.html. I guess it is not the best way, but I did not wish to break the animation effect. Or is there another better way?

So what i did was to create index.html and create many divs like:

```
example.com/index.html (Gallery)
example.com/index.html#box01 (About Us)
example.com/index.html#box02 (Homepage)
example.com/index.html#box03 (Contact Us)
```

I have tried to redirect using:

1. .htaccess (tried typing "DirectoryIndex index.html#box02" in .htaccess but fail to work)
2. tried redirecting using javascript in index.html:

   ```
   <script type ="text/javascript">
   function init(){
   location.href = "index.html#box02";
   }
   </script>

   <body onLoad="init()">
   ```

(but there is a lag time, as it loads index.html first, then it loads index.html#02)

**Is it possible to load index.html#box02 straightaway instead of index.html?**)

Would like to get help from more experienced web designers here?

Answer (score 0):

Everything after the `#` is for the browser to handle (and not the server), so changes on the server will not really make a difference. Your javascript solution is a good way to go about it.

One other way you can address this is to make the contents of `example.com/index.html#box02` available at `index.html` itself, by perhaps rendering it on load.

Nevertheless, the lag time you mention for the javascript solution is going to be present either way, as long as javascript is rendering the panning effect (which I believe is the case). I don't think your javascript solution will add significant lag here

Comment: thanks for your reply! Am trying to think of ways to remove the lag time. The lag time is obvious online. Offline, the lag time can't be seen.

Comment: Are you sure the lag time is between the completion of page load and start of the # change? I believe the lag times are due to the time it takes to load the pages and the scripts themselves. Your observation that this happens only online confirms this fact. You should look at page speed optimization to reduce that lag time

Comment: Thanks for your advice. But I guess there would still be a small 'flicker' from index.html to index.html#box02, no matter how small I optimize the pages? Is there any other way to instantly load index.html#box02?